# Flag for WebApps

Tags: feature-request, flags

I'm following the social media development threads closely on StackOverFlow and am noticing a fair amount of questions that I've needed to flag as off-topic belonging to [webapps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com). Since Webapps is out of beta. Can we add it to the official flag off-topic list?

Comment: Web Apps is not for developing web apps if that's what you're hinting.

Comment: I know, that's why I'm flagging the posts. I'm just asking for a flag icon for webapps. Like there is for webmasters, meta, programmers, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe Jeff has said that each site only gets up to 5 migration paths total, and that won't be changing.  There are fewer migrations from SO to Web Apps than there are to SO's 5 current migration sites, so Web Apps won't be getting put in there.

Comment: oh yeah, i do recall hearing about the 5 migration path total in a podcast i think. Good enough, i guess there are statistics to determine this.

Comment: Well, I've met a lot of questions not being bad by themselves but being on topic on WebApps or WebMasters. I think that in case of StackOverflow 5 targets are far too little.